# Is giving into ones desires shirk?

Tags: shirk

Is giving into ones desires shirk? I'm trying to understand this verse.
Does that mean when we know something is wrong, yet we still do it its shirk, is this a major or minor form of shirk?

> > أَفَرَأَيْتَ مَنِ اتَّخَذَ إِلَٰهَهُ هَوَاهُ وَأَضَلَّهُ اللَّهُ عَلَىٰ عِلْمٍ وَخَتَمَ عَلَىٰ سَمْعِهِ وَقَلْبِهِ وَجَعَلَ عَلَىٰ بَصَرِهِ غِشَاوَةً فَمَن يَهْدِيهِ مِن بَعْدِ اللَّهِ ۚ أَفَلَا تَذَكَّرُونَ - 45:23
> >
> > "Have you seen he who has taken as his god his [own] desire, and Allah has sent him astray due to knowledge and has set a seal upon his hearing and his heart and put over his vision a veil? So who will guide him after Allah ? Then will you not be reminded?"

Also found this  https://islamqa.info/en/126005

> > It was narrated that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: When the words “It is those who believe (in the Oneness of Allaah and worship none but Him Alone) and confuse not their Belief with Zulm (wrong)…” [al-‘An’aam 6:82] were revealed, the companions of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) were distressed by that and said: Who among us has not wronged himself? The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “It is not as you think; rather it is shirk. Have you not heard what Luqmaan said to his son when exhorting him: ‘O my son! Join not in worship others with Allaah. Verily, joining others in worship with Allaah is a great Zulm (wrong) indeed’ [Luqmaan 31:13]?”
> >
> > Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: 
> >     If what the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) meant in the words “rather it is shirk” was major shirk, then what he meant was that the one who is not one of the people of shirk is safe from the threat of punishment in this world and in the Hereafter that is issued to the mushrikeen, and he is among the guided. But if what he meant is shirk in general terms, then it may said: when a person wrongs himself, such as withholding – because of his love of wealth – and not doing some obligatory duties, this is minor shirk; and loving that which Allaah hates so that he gives his whims and desires precedence over love of Allaah, this is minor shirk, and so on. The one who does that has missed out on security and guidance commensurate with the level of his shirk,

but then again i also found this.
https://islamqa.info/en/276

> > Forbidden love:
> >      This includes love which constitutes shirk, which is when a person loves something instead of Allaah or as much as Him. In such a case he has taken that thing as a rival to Allaah. This is the shirk of love, and most people have taken things as rivals to Allaah in love and glorification.

How is the above statement different to this one bellow?
One is saying its shirk, one is saying it isn't?

> > There are also types of forbidden love which do not go to the extent of shirk, such as loving one’s family, wealth, tribe, business or house, and preferring those things, in whole or in part, over doing the duties that Allaah requires of him, such as hijrah (migration for His sake), jihaad, etc. The daleel (evidence) for this is the aayah quoted above (“Say: If your fathers, your sons, your brothers, your wives, your kindred, the wealth that you have gained, the commerce in which you fear a decline, and the dwellings in which you delight . . . are dearer to you than Allaah and His Messenger, and striving hard and fighting in His cause, then wait until Allaah brings about His Decision (torment).” [al-Tawbah 9:24])

We all fall have desires and even though we know they are wrong we still do them, does this constitute shirk? I have read in some places that it is a type of Shirk al Muhabbah (Shirk of Love). A major shirk,  wouldnt that then mean that everytime we give into our desires knowingly we commit shirk?

Say if one likes listening to music or watching TV (Hollywood Movies ect), we know its not right, but we still do it. So does that mean we commit shirk?

Comment: Does the verse indicate any shirk?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Well thats what i want to find out, Allah here says that one has taken his own desire as god. So does giving into ones desires constitute a form of shirk?

Answer (score 1):

There's no contradiction in any of these quotes. Some are just focused on the "minor" whereas others are speaking on the "major". If we are going to categorize "giving into ones desires" as a form of shirk, then it would be the 'minor' kind.

There's a difference between "giving into your desires" vs. "taking your desires as a god" (major shirk). The difference is that in the first situation ("giving into your desires"), your original intent is following Allah's (ﷻ) guidance and you still acknowledge your actions as being wrong even when you do them.

In contrast, to "take your desires as a god" means you are totally disregarding Allah's (ﷻ)  guidance to begin with; it is irrelevant to you. Rather, you do what you want and make up your own decision on whether something  is right/wrong based on whims/desires. (e.g., if you like music, alcohol, etc.. you view them as Halal regardless of what Allah (ﷻ) [or His Messenger] says). To declare Halal what Allah (ﷻ) said is Haram or to make up your own rules is Shirk, because you are trying to have a share in Judgement when Allah (ﷻ) said He doesn't share His Judgement with anyone.

> "He shares not His legislation with anyone" (Qur'an 18:26).

As for the "Shirk of love", it is the same principle in general. You love to do something and it makes you sin.. this is minor. But if you love something more than or equal to Allah (ﷻ) [giving as much veneration to them as is supposed to be for Allah only] then that is major shirk.

Comment: Firstly, i really appreciate you replying to my question. So, would you saying giving into your desires, knowing that it is wrong is a form of shirk, or simply a sin? If the former, that is everyone committing a form of shirk?

Comment: Personally, I only call that "minor shirk" which the Prophet defined. For example, he said acting in order to show off (Ryia) is "minor shirk". I wouldn't rush to say other things are. But scholars have more knowledge and their own Ijtihad. -- That said, assuming they are right...this is part of why people pray for forgiveness of intentional and unintentional + major and minor Shirk/Kufr/sins.

Comment: I appreciate your response. It really is something very scary, if we're all falling into such a sin and it were shirk. Everyone giving into there nafs, would be falling into it.
Allah knows best.

Comment: I still am a little confused on Shirk or love, there does seem to be a little bit of a contradiction to what i posted between the two quotes? One is saying that it is shirk and another say it dosn't reach the extent of shirk?

"Forbidden love: This includes love which constitutes shirk, which is when a person loves something instead of Allaah or as much as Him. "

vs
"forbidden love which do not go to the extent of shirk, such as loving one’s family, wealth, tribe, business or house, and preferring those things, in whole or in part, over doing the duties that Allaah requires of him,".

Comment: but then Ibn Taymiyah is saying when you wrong yourself and give precedence to your desires, its a minor shirk?